# Powershell SQL Server Insert - Best Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, foreach, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a script that iterates through a few thousand files in a directory on a daily basis and would like to update a SQL Server table with details of each file, as they are processed within the foreach loop.

I have this working already using the following within the foreach loop:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "INSERT INTO $dbTable (name, date, worknum, identifier) VALUES ('$name','$date','$worknum','$identifier')" 
              -ServerInstance $dbHost -Database $dbName -ErrorAction Stop
```

Although this works fine, I'd like to know if there would be any benefit to changing this method to establishing a SQL Server connection before the processing of the files starts and closing it at the end of the script?  Something like this..

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dbHost;Database=$dbName;Integrated Security=True;"

<foreach loop>

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

I'm not concerned with the speed that the script runs as its already pretty fast, just more with regard to not affecting DB performance.

Comment: If the script runs quickly it's probably not a problem, but it would help to know roughly the number of rows you expect to insert. If it's a large number, working in one large transaction can reduce log size.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there will be no noticable difference because SQL-Server/ADO.NET uses [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling). But to know it you have to test it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments chaps.  It inserts a single row per file processed so approx 2k per day.  Think I'll leave script as it is.  Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you will need to test against your instance configuration and existing workload to determine if a solution is performant or not.

I had a similar experience with a PowerShell "app" that took a list of account identifiers and then INSERT them into a table for us to further process. The app was iterating over each ID and doing an INSERT for each ID originally. This was OK for most users, but occasionally someone would put 100k+ ids in and the performance on the app was horrid! (But the SQL server kept performing as expected) Using `SqlBulkCopy` speed that process up immensely for  the client side with no discernible impact on the SQL server as well. (Only the folks with lots of records got the benefit though. There was no real change from <100 records though. )

The [Write-DataTable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae/) and [Out-DataTable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd) are handy functions to have to make this easier.

My feelings out of the way, best practice....

Eugene Philipov has a [good article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/comparing-multiple-rows-insert-vs-single-row-insert-with-three-data-load-methods/) on tests that they did on data load method performance between single value inserts, multi value inserts, and BulkCopy. They found that the number of columns you are inserting into has a a large affect on the operation's speed. The more columns, the less of a benefit you get from having multiple values in your insert or using bulk copy. However, using a single insert per record was always slower (by execution time).

Faster execution == less chance you will block/consume resources that are needed for your other workflows.